# Object/instance exception when accessing listview column

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am using WinForms/VS2010 c# to create a listview with 12 columns and 8 rows.  Here is the snippet from the WinForms auto-coded file:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
       .....
    }
```

Then, in the Form1.cs file, I have the following method:

```
    // in my form1.cs file
    public void listView1_Populate()
    {
        var columnIndex = listView1.Columns[2].Index;
        int counter = 0;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
             if (item.SubItems[columnIndex].Text == "2")
             {
                 counter += 100;
                 item.SubItems[columnIndex].Text = counter.ToString(); 
             }
        }
    }
```

But I get the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception when the code hits the line:  `var columnIndex = listView1.Columns[2].Index;`

What am I doing wrong (other than trying to learn c# at age 54!)?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at that line and check the item.SubItems.Count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear from your question what is null referenced. But if you add the following before this line `var columnIndex = listView1.Columns[2].Index;` you might get a clearer understanding of whats going wrong.

```
if (listView1 == null)
    throw new Exception("listView1 is null");
if (listView1.Columns == null)
    throw new Exception("Columns is null");
if (listView1.Columns.Length < 3)
    throw new Exception("Columns length is out of range");
```

Comment: I added these statements in and found the problem.  All I had to do was change "if (listView1.Columns.Length < 3)" to "if (listView1.Columns.Count < 3)"

Comment: @user994179 ah sorry - its usually one of those two